# How to get goal completion locations by source in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am playing with Google analytics for a while and I am trying to pair Goal completion URLs with source by which user entered my website. Is it even possible ?

I need to know which eshop orders were made through certain sources. Any ideas or hints ? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a custom report:

[image]